# Dynamic View with add button, how to find unique edtxt ID or anything else

Tags: android, dynamic, view, addtextchangedlistener

I am building an android application where I am creating dynamic `EditText` View. I need to display the sum of all `EditText` on the top `TextView`. I am unable to find a way to do that, Can anyone help me with this.

And I am also not understanding, when I click on add button only one dynamic view seems to be LIVE, and rest seems to be sleeping....(***this is just a part of my program***...)

ThankYou in Advance.

Here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearBelowBoard"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="111dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Sum"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />
```

row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/button" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Java File

```
    package com.example.rajiv.aaaplusbutton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edt1;
    Button but_add, but_remove;
    TextView txtSum;
    LinearLayout linearBelowBoard;
    int e1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearBelowBoard = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearBelowBoard);

        txtSum=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalText);


        but_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        but_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


                edt1 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

                edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                              int count) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                  int after) {
                        if (s.length() > 0) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        calCheck();
                    }
                });


                Button but_remove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                final View.OnClickListener thisListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                };

                but_remove.setOnClickListener(thisListener);
                linearBelowBoard.addView(addView);


            }

        });

    }



    public void calCheck() {

        try {
            e1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
            txtSum.setText(Integer.toString(" What to Do? "));

        } catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to solve your problem:  I made some changes in your code Try with this:

```
package com.cj.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by CHETAN JOSHI on 3/6/2017.
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edt1;
    Button but_add, but_remove;
    TextView txtSum;
    LinearLayout linearBelowBoard;
    int e1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        linearBelowBoard = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearBelowBoard);
        txtSum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalText);
        but_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        but_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


                edt1 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                edt1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(edt1));
                Button but_remove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                final View.OnClickListener thisListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                };

                but_remove.setOnClickListener(thisListener);
                linearBelowBoard.addView(addView);

            }

        });

    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        EditText mEditText = null;

        public MyTextWatcher(EditText mEditText) {
            this.mEditText = mEditText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            calCheck(mEditText);
        }
    }

    public void calCheck(EditText editText) {
  try {
        if (linearBelowBoard != null) {
            e1 =0;
            for (int i = 0; i < linearBelowBoard.getChildCount(); i++) {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)linearBelowBoard.getChildAt(i);
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                View view = relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
                EditText editText1 = null;
                if (view instanceof EditText) {
                    editText1 = (EditText) view;
                } else {
                    view = relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
                    editText1 = (EditText) view;
                }
                String str = editText1.getText().toString();
                if(str!=null && !str.equals("") && str.length()>0)
                e1 = e1 + Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            }
            }
        txtSum.setText("" + String.valueOf(e1));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

[image]

Please Check I crate one more method that return `EditText` by passing position.
So you need to pass any position up to added counts of `EditText` then you will get `EditText`   and you can getText().toString().

update calCheck() method:

```
  public void calCheck(EditText editText) {
        try {
            if (linearBelowBoard != null) {
                e1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < linearBelowBoard.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    EditText editText1 = getEditTextFromPosition(i);
                    String str = editText1.getText().toString();
                    if (str != null && !str.equals("") && str.length() > 0)
                        e1 = e1 + Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            txtSum.setText("" + String.valueOf(e1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Use Below Method to get Editext:

```
    private EditText getEditTextFromPosition(int position){
        EditText editText=null;
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)linearBelowBoard.getChildAt(position);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
        View view = relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);

        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            editText = (EditText) view;
        } else {
            view = relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
            editText = (EditText) view;
        }
        return editText;
    }
```

Comment: Nice one tnx for it.. but i would like to add all editText Fileds...
txtSum.setText("" + String.valueOf(e1));
what needs to be done there......?

Comment: yes I know just a minute i will update my code with this.

Comment: Chetan can u point out why my code could not keep all edittxt Live or active

Comment: No Your code all of your EditText are Live but you have know which one is active at the movement and but in my I have create one seprate class MyTextWatcher  that implements TextWatcher and added constructor init . so each time i know which EditText have focused .

Comment: Hi Chetan  it would be great if you could tell me on how to getText from txtSum ,I tried with your concept but since your code is inside try catch am unable to getText for each text change which I need for further operation to be made in my program thanks

Comment: means you need text while changing Text in particular EditText  OR you need create List of each EditText  value at end .

Comment: in the above Image u have entered values 6,9,11,99... i would like to know how to use getText.toString()....for each individual editText.... so i could use them for other purpose....

Comment: in calCheck() method parameter editText is reference of  current editext is in focus. and under for loop edittext1 holds each added Editext with respect to their loop position including current focused EditText. So while loops running you can make List of Edittext menas you can hold there refrences.

Comment: Hi Chetan sorry for troubling you again and again since am a newbei I am asking this what I exactly wanna do in my project is I have a button with + on clicking that n times n number of EditText,Text View opens and in the edit text if I type a number the texxtview below calculates the value and shows in the corresponding TextView I need which edit text is changed and what is row in which edit text is changed to find the addition according to the specific + symbol and show it in the particular text view.So need  the get text of the edit text how can I get that could you tell me .Thanks

Comment: **Sure Sure Tnx a lot**.....it would be gr8 if u explain me with a code again.....

Comment: @RajivReddy yes

Comment: sweet....i have a new issue, now my requirement is not sum but to print in txtView

https://github.com/raj5140/AAAplusButton-master

check this github...u will know the issue, the result comes for only one view. i want it to print for all...in same way

Comment: so you can get TextView like you get EditText by position.

Comment: Chetan any clue?

Comment: yes I saw below pic and your taking Board Size  and from EditText and multiplication must be display in next TextView.

Comment: So we get EditText from method we made you can also get TextView too.

Comment: Yes...but i get only the one where cursor is available, not the others...

Comment: no you can call outside method that return TextView outSide of Text Watcher

Comment: i did not get you...could you show me in code...that would be great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138203/discussion-between-chetan-and-rajiv-reddy).

Comment: calCheck2() method outside of afterTextChanged() . its also working.

Comment: any clue bro..?